# Codehaus: difference between existing and installed configuration?

Tags: tomcat, build, cargo, maven-cargo

I understand there are various configurations for any container in a cargo using [codehaus](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Home.html).

However all these configurations can be a bit confusing. Can anyone tell me the exact difference in concept and implementation of the configurations `installed` and `existing`?

Answer (score 0):

There are several combinations of containers and configurations available in Cargo:

[Remote container](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Remote+Container.html) - Container which is already started somewhere (can be on localhost or somewhere else) and Cargo doesn't control it.
For this container type can be used just Runtime configuration. In this combination Cargo can just deploy applications to remote container.

[Installed container](https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Installed+Container.html) - Container which is installed locally and Cargo controls its starting and stopping.
This container can have Standalone or Existing configuration:

- Existing configuration: Expects that user already created configuration(domain) with all settings and configuration. Cargo controls starting of container, deploying applications to it and stopping container.
- Standalone configuration: Configuration(domain) creation is handled by Cargo. User just have to provide container installation, for some containers Cargo is able to download and install container by itself. Here Cargo controls domain creation, configuring its datasources and resources(if supported), setting container properties, users and roles, deploying applications, starting and stopping of container.

Embedded container - Used for embedded containers, can be used just with Standalone configuration.